# Using email instead of username in CakePHP Auth Component

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am working on cakephp 2.x . my problem is i dont want to use username for logging .. i am taking the email and password from the user and verify this email and password from the database
 i have a table in my database name **user** and it has 3 fields 
**id**, 
**email** and 
**password**

here is my code

**Model**

```
 <?php
class User extends AppModel {
public $useTable = 'user';
}
?>
```

**AppController**

```
 class AppController extends Controller {
   public $components = array(
   'Session',
'Auth'=>array(
    'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'admin'),
    'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'admin'),
    'authError'=>"You can't access that page",
    'authorize'=>array('Controller') 
   )
);

public function isAuthorized($user) {
}

  public function beforeFilter() {
  $this->Auth->allow('index');
```

**UserController**

```
public function login()
   {
     if ($this->request->is('post')) {
       if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Your email/password combination was incorrect');
    }
}
}
```

**login.ctp**

```
 <?php


   echo $this->form->create();

  echo $this->form->input('email');
  echo $this->form->input('password');


    echo $this->form->end('Authenticate');
   ?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure it with:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

See also [Configuring Authentication handlers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) in the cookbook.

Comment: sorry 2 ask this silly question..where should i add your code ? or please if you can adjust your code within my code so i can instantly run this and inform you about the output

Comment: It's just a new entry with the key `authenticate` in the `Auth` array you already have in your `AppController`.

Comment: do i have to change field name in login.ctp from email to 'username' ?